# Scala IDE on Eclipse Luna is not displaying scala Worksheet

Tags: scala-ide

I have installed scala IDE 4.0.0 on Eclipse Luna.

It is not displaying Scala Worksheet option which is displayed on Scala IDE 3.0.2 on Eclipse Kepler.

Could anyone tell me is Scala Worksheet feature is removed in version 4.0.0 or is it a bug or some workaround I should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled the scala plugin and re-installed the same. Now it is working fine.

Comment: This didn't work for me - I still can't create a worksheet feature

Comment: Hi nathan, could you please provide more details like version of eclipse you are using , steps you have used to add scala ide plugin to eclipse, and screenshots if you can provide, that will be helpful.

Comment: I added the update site to my existing Luna installation and selected the Scala plugins plus the worksheet plugin.  When I right-click on my scala project, "create new worksheet" item is displayed.  Is that where it's supposed to be?  It's not in the "New ->" wizards either.

Comment: That being said, I just did the same steps on another computer and I can create a worksheet there.  I'll see if I can figure out any differences between the 2.

Comment: I removed the PyDev and Android dev tools from my original Eclipse installation and then I was able to get Scala Worksheet to work as expected.  I don't know whether that's related or not.

Comment: sorry Nathan. I am not conversant with PyDev at all.

Answer (score 3):

Go to help->install new software
Put this link in the URL
http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/stable/site

and select Scala IDE plugins(incubation)

U can do next and install this plugin.